# Compare strings of different dimensions

Tags: string, matlab, strcmp

I have the string s1 and s2

```
s1={'1' '631' '618' '574' '678'} 
s2={'1' '596' '674' '' '';'674' '631' '1' '631' '1';'641' '617' '674' '631' '654';'674' '673' '674' '673' '674';'674' '618' '1' '618' '631';'631' '1' '631' '674' '740';'739' '740' '733' '674' '631';'674' '673' '674' '1' '641';'618' '1' '631' '618' '631';'674' '631' '618' '631' '618';'674' '631' '1' '631' '625';'641' '642' '618' '631' '618';'618' '631' '1' '631' '1'}
```

I want to compare s1 and its substrings

```
{'1'}
{'1' '631'}
{'1' '631' '618'}
{'1' '631' '618' '574'}
{'1' '631' '618' '574' '678'}
{'631'}
{'631' '618'}
{'631' '618' '574'}
{'631' '618' '574' '678'}
{'618'}
{'618' '574'}
{'618' '574' '678'}
{'574'}
{'574' '678'}
{'678'}
```

with s2: I have used strcmp(s1,s2) but I don't obtain the expected result. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly suggest converting all your strings in to numbers and use matrix operations instead of string operations:

```
S1 = cellfun(@str2num, s1)
S2 = cell2mat(str2double (s2)) %// NOTE its str2double here which converts any empty string or char into a NaN
```

now do the compare, if you want intersect (which I think you are)

```
[intersect ind] =  ismember(S2,S1);
```

If you want to stick with Strings, you can do something like this which is much more efficient:

```
ind=find(ismember(s2,s1{1}))
>> ind =

 1
19
22
28
31
37
39
47
54
65
```

The problem with `strcmp` is that it compares 2 strings and returns a logical, in your case, you are facing 5*65 operations, which is time consuming and terrible to process in general. so the `ismember` function is your best choice.

To generate the "s1 and its substrings", you can use `combnk` such as:

```
V = combnk(S1,1)
V = combnk(S1,2) %//change 1 to 5 based on the combinations.
```

Comment: For `str2double` you don't need to wrap it in `cellfun` and `cellmat`. Just do `str2double(s2)` as it can accept a cell array of strings.

Comment: @Suever ohhh  nice one, didn't see that one